# How to stop users from editing a single row in MS Access Table?

Tags: ms-access, permissions, locking, row, ms-access-2016

I have a row in a table which I use for auto-numbering other fields in the same table, if this row is edited it can mess up the sequence. How can I stop users who are making use of this database from editing this one particular row?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If a user or process creates a new record but regrets the action, the number is lost.

The Autonumber is designed to uniquely identify the individual record, nothing else. If you need a sequence number or similar for any other purpose, roll you own function. There are plenty of examples out there for the browsing.